# Сброс отметок всех чекбоксов

Tags: jquery, checkbox, cookie, javascript, ucoz

Все работает, а сброс отметок всех чекбоксов, не пойму, в чем может быть проблема?

Когда нажимаешь на ссылку - снять все отметки с чекбоксов, должны сбрасываться и настройки фильтра... Отметки снимаются, а настройки фильтра не сбрасывается!?

Просто по клику на чекбокс, все работает как часы... помогите понять, в чем дело?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {

        var id = this.getAttribute('id');
        var name = this.getAttribute('name');
        var value = this.getAttribute('value');

        if (id == undefined) return;
        if (this.checked) {
            categoryFilter('other' + name, value); //сортируем каталог
            $.cookie('check' + name, value); //сохраняем значение в куку
        } else {
            categoryFilter('other' + name, '');
            $.cookie('check' + name, '');
        }
    });

    //выводим состояние чекбоксов
    var isCheck = false;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        isCheck = $.cookie("check" + i);

        if (isCheck) {
            $('#ch' + i).attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            $('#ch' + i).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }

    //снимаем все отметки c чекбоксов
    $("#select_none").click(function () {
        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            $('#ch' + i).removeAttr('checked');
            categoryFilter('other' + i, '');
            $.cookie('check' + i, '');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: у вас фильтры в куках хранятся, а вы при сбросе фильтра cookies не затираете

Comment: $.cookie('check' + i, ''); - а это что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может в categoryFilter проблема? Или вот тут:

```
$("#select_none").click(function () {
    //...    
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное надо или

```
$.cookie('check' + name, null);
```

или

```
isCheck = $.cookie("check" + i) != '';
```

Мне кажется что `isCheck = $.cookie("check" + i)` будет true даже если значение ''